# How to set 'AutomationExtension' as false in wdio.conf.js file in webdriverio?

Tags: webdriver-io, wdio-v5

I am new to WebdriverIO. I want to know how to set 'AutomationExtension' as false in wdio.conf.js file in webdriverio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it as below in your config file for Chrome.

```
{
  'maxInstances': 1,
  'browserName': 'chrome',
  'goog:chromeOptions': {
    w3c: true,
    args: ['--headless'],
    useAutomationExtension: false,
  },
},
```